# How to create a class in a js file in a meteor-based website?

Tags: class, oop, meteor

Why does this code does not work?

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
}
```

If I try to call `Apple`, I get the error message

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Apple is not defined(…)
>
> (anonymous function) @ VM1844:2
>
> InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM1757:875
>
> InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM1757:808
>
> InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1757:664

Comment: Whe need to know more code for check scopes... where is declaration and where the invocation or call

Comment: What do you mean by declaration? It is in a `file.js` file. I know that the code there is executed (I can log). The invocation is from the debugger. If I do `console.log(Apple);` in the js file, it works.

Comment: It seems the code of `file1.js` is executed but not "seen" by `file2.js`.

Comment: I mean in meteor there are some conventions and client server and both scopes, also theres a rule that the first file is called is main.js anyway print this inside de block where you are executing and you will know in wich scope you are , after you can play with bind method to chain..

Comment: See my edit of the message.

Comment: Your edit is a typo, your first issue is likely a scope issue.

Comment: Also check this http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp , so meteor have startups methods.. scope conventions ..etc..

Comment: @JoaquinJavi Thanks for your help!! Do you understand why the code does not work (in More code)?

Comment: Ok! it was a stupid typo!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something global in `Meteor`, don't prefix with `var`.

So, this should work!

```
Apple = function (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answers of the targeted question. If your question is a duplicate of the targeted question you should not post an answer but validate the duplicate.